# Como é contabilizada as requisições à API do GMAP?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Em um sistema interno, há uma simples plotagem de uma rota A - B em uma das páginas. Recentemente essa página está recebendo uma quantidade maior de requisições e consequentemente requisitando o gmap mais vezes.

Eu quero implementar uma forma de que apenas requisite e renderize o gmap após um click.

O que eu quero saber é:
As requisições à `API` do `GMAP` são contabilizadas a partir do carregamento do script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Ou do método `load`

```
google.load(module, version)
```

Pois assim saberei como alterar melhor para evitar requisições dispensáveis à `API`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente você será cobrado sempre que carregar um **mapa**/**imagem** na tela e não quando carregar somente o script do Google Maps no seu site.

Você sera cobrado quando:

- Uma página web ou aplicativo exibir um mapa usando a API do Google Maps JavaScript
- A página da Web ou aplicativo exibe um Google Street View Imagem API usando a API do Google Maps JavaScript. Se um panorama do Street View substitui um mapa no mesmo elemento div, o panorama não é cobrado.
- Um aplicativo solicita uma imagem do mapa do Google Static Maps API.
- Um aplicativo solicita uma imagem panorâmica do Google Street View Imagem API

Fonte:
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload